# Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Linq.IQueryable’ to ‘System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable’

Tags: asp.net, boilerplate, abp

I am trying to search the product name using the given keyword but my boilerplate throw me error

I tried

```
protected override IQueryable<Product> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedProductResultRequestDto input)
{
    return base.CreateFilteredQuery(input).
        WhereIf(input.Keyword.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), x => x.Name.Contains(input.Keyword));
}
```

gave me error

> Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Linq.IQueryable’ to
>   ‘System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable’. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The error tells you the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: try returning as IQueryable<Product>.This will work

Comment: something like return YourResult as IQueryable<Product>

Answer (score 3):

Fix your `using` directive.

```cs
// using Abp.Collections.Extensions; // EnumerableExtensions.WhereIf returns IEnumerable<T>
   using Abp.Linq.Extensions;        // QueryableExtensions.WhereIf returns IQueryable<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected IQueryable<Product> CreateFilteredCategory(Collection<Product> input)
    {
        return input.Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains("Test")).AsQueryable<Product>();
    }
```

The classes aren't exactly the same, but the premise is.